# How can I configure my node js project with admin LTE template?

Tags: node.js, adminlte

I am a novice with Nodejs, I try to integrate admin LTE templates into my node project. but I can't succeed.

They could correct what I'm doing wrong in the configuration

> **package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "node-admin",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "admin-lte": "^3.0.4",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0"
  }
}
```

> **index.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
let app = express();

const path = require('path');
const morgan = require('morgan');


app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use('/css', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/admin-lte/dist')));
app.use('/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/admin-lte/dist')));
app.use('/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/jquery/dist')));
app.use('/img', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/admin-lte/dist')));
app.set('admin-lte', './node_modules');

app.use('/admin', express.static('./node_modules/admin-lte'));

app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log("Listenning on PORT 3001 >> http://localhost:3001");

})
```

> **admin-lte folder in node_modules**

[image]

> **proyecto node**

[image]

Comment: I have no issues running your example... what error are you seeing? here's a screen dump of mine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0O5Md.png

Comment: when I run the program and try to display the index.html in my browser I get "Cannot GET /" when I should get the Admin LTE template index

Comment: @MarceloEscalera, I am facing same issue like yours. Did you solved this? Please let me know..

Comment: Sorry for replying late, but I couldn't fix the problem and you could?

Comment: If it's on a development server like localhost, change the port number to 3000.

Answer (score 1):

Dears your pointing to

```
app.use('/admin', express.static('./node_modules/admin-lte'));
```

if type http://localhost:3001/admin/ you will get adminlte interface, you need to do that or change previous line to:

```
app.use('/', express.static('./node_modules/admin-lte'));
```